# from left to right direction in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, animation

i want to make my box animation come up from left to right direction, right now my box appear from top to buttom, how can i change my move direction of the box from left to right, i have nine box and three each other line, like picture below

[image]

here is my current code

```
function random_item()
{
    var listItem:Array = new Array();
    for (var i:uint=0; i<15; i++)
    {
        listItem.push(i);
    }
    ItemLeft = 0;
    for (var x:uint=0; x<boardWidth; x++)
    {
        for (var y:uint=0; y<boardHeight; y++)
        {
            var thisItem:FirstBox = new FirstBox();
            thisItem.stop();
            thisItem.x = x * IcardHorizontalSpacing + IboardOffsetX;
            thisItem.y = y * IcardVerticalSpacing + IboardOffsetY;
            var r:uint = Math.floor(Math.random() * listItem.length);
            thisItem.cardface = listItem[r];
            listItem.splice(r,1);
            thisItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickItem);
            thisItem.buttonMode = true;
            addChild(thisItem);
            ItemLeft++;
        }
    }

}
```

how do i make the animation from left to right, thanks before

Comment: There's no animation code in there, so it's hard to tell what's going wrong. But to create an animation going from left to right, just increase the x-coordinate of `thisItem`. A very simple way to create animations is to use TweenMax: http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/

Answer (score 0):

Since your nested `for` loop has the y-position nested inside the x-position, three y positions (top, middle, bottom) will appear for each x-position.

You might be able to fix the behavior you are seeing by structuring your `for` loop like below, switching the order of the variables:

```
for (var y:uint=0; y<boardHeight; y++)
{
    for (var x:uint=0; x<boardWidth; x++)
    {
        //Inner code remains the same
    }
}
```

This way, three x-positions will be displayed for each y-position, hopefully creating the left-to-right behavior you're looking for.

Comment: i have tried it, but it seems work like the first one, the direction still from left top to left bottom

Answer (score 0):

```
//change
for (var y:uint=0; y<boardHeight; y++)

//to
for (var y:uint=boardHeight; y>0; y--)
```

Although, in your code you are nesting the y loop inside the x loop.
This means that for every iteration of the X loop the box will go from bottom to top
I don't know if this is the what you are looking for.
Please be more specific in your description of what you want.

Comment: yeah that what i mean, i have change the code, it works just for first three box at the top (left to right) but the other box not is gone (not appear)

Answer (score 0):

You are looping first over x and then over y. This means that it will add 3 items for every column. Invert the loops to get it to add 3 items for every row.

```
function random_item()
{
    var listItem:Array = new Array();
    for (var i:uint=0; i<15; i++)
    {
        listItem.push(i);
    }
    ItemLeft = 0;
    for (var y:uint=0; y<boardHeight; y++)
    {
        for (var x:uint=0; x<boardWidth; x++)
        {
            var thisItem:FirstBox = new FirstBox();
            thisItem.stop();
            thisItem.x = x * IcardHorizontalSpacing + IboardOffsetX;
            thisItem.y = y * IcardVerticalSpacing + IboardOffsetY;
            var r:uint = Math.floor(Math.random() * listItem.length);
            thisItem.cardface = listItem[r];
            listItem.splice(r,1);
            thisItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickItem);
            thisItem.buttonMode = true;
            addChild(thisItem);
            ItemLeft++;
        }
    }

}
```